# how can i make unque id in jQuery and send to the html

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, laravel

id = menu_selected_id sending each value by loop but when i receiving the data in HTML it just showing the first value. i think because of the unique id it happening

My question is how can i make a unque id for this menu_id_selected in html and jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name="menu_item_category_selected"]').on('change', function() {
    var countryID = $(this).val();
    if (countryID) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/menu/item/entry1/' + countryID,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $('select[id="menu_selected_id"]').empty();
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('select[id="menu_selected_id"]').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      $('select[id="menu_selected_id"]').empty();
    }
  }).change();
});
```

````html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="menu_category" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Menu Category') }}</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-select" name="menu_item_category_selected" id="menu_item_category_selected">
      <option value="Menu Item" disabled> --Select Menu Category-- </option>
      @foreach($menu_category as $role)
      <option value="{{$role->id}}">{{$role->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="menu" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Menu') }}</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select class="form-select" name="menu_id_selected" id="menu_selected_id">
      <option value="" disabled>--Select Menu--</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```
````

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please replace the templating with rendered HTML in a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for editing. But i need a solution

Comment: Hi, please elaborate more i,e : what do you mean by first value ?

Comment: There is some table data. When I click the Edit button for a particular column then the menu category and the menu name show dropdown. Similarly, the code that I have written shows the values selected for the first row but not the second selected or so on